# Create a CMake object library from other object libraries (akin to relocatable output using ld)

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following code structure

```
Project->
    project.cxx
    CMakeLists.txt
    meta->
        CMakeLists.txt   
        first->
           first.cxx
           CMakeLists.txt
        second->
           second.cxx
           CMakeLists.txt
```

where first/CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
FILE(GLOB first_sources "*.cxx")
ADD_LIBRARY(first OBJECT ${first_sources})
```

second/CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
FILE(GLOB second_sources "*.cxx")
ADD_LIBRARY(second OBJECT ${second_sources})
```

meta/CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(first)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(second)
ADD_LIBRARY(meta OBJECT $<TARGET_OBJECTS:first> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:second>)
```

and finally, Project/CMakeLists.txt containts:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(meta)
FILE(GLOB Project_SOURCES "*.cxx")
ADD_LIBRARY(Project SHARED ${Project_SOURCES} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:meta>)
```

However,

```
ADD_LIBRARY(meta OBJECT $<TARGET_OBJECTS:first> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:second>)
```

fails given that OBJECT library expects c/cxx sources instead of object files.

What I am trying to achieve is a relocatable object file that combines both first.o and second.o into a meta.o as:

```
ld -r first.o second.o -o meta.o
```

What would be the CMake alternative for the same?